# C3.js Legend Labels using JSON data

Tags: json, d3.js, legend, c3.js

I have a donut graph, with a legend, that I made in C3.js.
Actually, I do this to fill the chart.

```
var chartDonut = c3.generate({....});
chartDonut.load({
            columns: [
                ['Parfait', 190],
                ['Bien', 120],
                ['Trop court', 32],
                ['Trop long', 22],
            ],
            names: {
                'Parfait': 'Parfait (entre 50 \340 60 car.)',
                'Bien': 'Bien (entre 40 \340 49 ou  61 \340 69 car.)',
                'Trop court': 'Trop court (inf\351rieur \340 40 car.)',
                'Trop long': 'Trop long (sup\351rieur \340 79 car.)'            
            },
});
```

Everything works the way that I want it to, but I want to use JSON data.
I do this

```
chartDonut.load({
            json: [
                    {"Parfait": 190},
                    {"Bien": 190},
                    {"Trop court": 190},
                    {"Trop long": 190}
            ],
            keys: {
                value: ['Parfait', 'Bien', 'Trop court', 'Trop long']
            },
});
```

but I have not found how to have the `names` properties in JSON format.
Can someone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what your problem is, but you can actually just add the `names` attribute to the object with the same content as above, similar as in your first solution. This will lead to the same output.

I created a jsFiddle, where I just copied your code (and switched from `.load` to the initial `.generate`) and added the `names` attribute to the the second object. See [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k7maLz8r/1/).